# How Do I Take The Green Triangle from a number Cell R When I Write To An Excel Sheet?

Tags: r, excel, conditional-formatting, openxlsx

**My Code:**

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
saveWorkbook(wb, "mergeCellsExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

writeData(wb ,sheet= 1 ,as.data.frame(1,2,3,5,6 ,7),  startCol= 1 , startRow = 1 )
saveWorkbook(wb, "mergeCellsExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

I want it without the green triangle that I circled as a number . I am only using openxlsx package.

Comment: Are you sure Excel is seeing the number as a number and not as text? If you click on the cell, a small `!` icon should appear to the left of it, if you click on that, an explanation of the problem should show up.

Comment: But how do i fix it so it originally registers it as number and not as a text

Comment: Has any of the answers helped you with your problem, nesha?

Answer (score 0):

Try unhook the "Numbers formatted as text" in Excel's config session "Error Checking".

As you can see, I'm using a MacOS right now, but I believe Excel on Windows have the same config option somewhere, you can try to find out by yourself.

Also, I think this issue belongs to office, rather than R.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your numbers are turning into text is that your data frame is just a header in Excel. This will be solved by creating a "header" in your data frame. You can then remove it in the `writeData` function by setting `colNames = FALSE`.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
saveWorkbook(wb, "mergeCellsExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
mydata <- data.frame("1" =1,
"2" = 2)

writeData(wb ,sheet= 1 ,mydata,  startCol= 1 , startRow = 1,
          colNames = FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "mergeCellsExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]